# How are big O notation equations assigned in search algorithms?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

For linear search it makes sense that the run time **is big O of N** since it will always be one step. As for my understanding of bubble sort it's runtime is **O of n^2** this makes sense to me because you'd iterate the number of elements in the an array and each time compare two values till the end of said array.

But for merge sort it's always splitting the data in half, so I'm confused as to explanation as to why the run time is n log n. Additionally I want to clarify my understanding of insertion sorts runtime **big O of n^2**. Since insertion sort looks for the smallest number then compares it to every single number of the array it would be n^2 because it will loop through the array contents for every iteration.

If I could be given some advice about merge sort, and general understanding of run times that'd be appreciated. I am an absolute newbie and wanted to throw that disclaimer out there.

Comment: Just do it manually for a few examples and count.

Comment: Merge Sort merges **n** elements **log n** times. As this is a perpetual question (it’s tough!), there is an extant answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297160/why-is-mergesort-olog-n

Comment: I agree -- but not the top answer, this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/297203/3673

Comment: I also agree with @PresidentJamesK.Polk - this is how I did it in high school to get a feeling for it -- I took a deck of playing cards, shuffled them and then did all the types of sorts on them.  It becomes clear when you have to do it by hand which one is going faster fundamentally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that sorting of an array of `N` elements is taking `T(N)` time. In merge sort we know that we need to sort two arrays of `N/2` elements (that is `2*T(N/2)`) and then merge them (in `O(N)` time complexity, that is `c*N` for some constant `c`).
So, `T(N) = 2T(N/2) + c*N`.
We could stop here, as it is basically the "equation" you asking about. But let's go a bit further.

To simplify things, we can show that `T(N) = kN log N` as follows (for some constant `k`):

Let's substitute T on both sides of the equation we have derived:

`kN log N = 2 * k*(N/2) log (N/2) + c*N`

and expand the right hand side (assuming `log` with base `2`):
 `= k*N *(log N - log 2) + c*N = k*N *(log N - 1) + c*N = kNlog N + (c-k)N`

That is for `c=k` the equality holds, and it proves that `T(N)` if of a form `kN log N`, that is `O(N log N)`

Comment: thanks so much after looking through a diagram with the math above from Hogan it clicked!